# useState in "React Native" does not display initial value when I change my code

Tags: react-native, use-state, expo

I have a problem with useState hook in my React Native app.
My app doesn't refresh the state to its initial value when I modify my code. I have this problem in both "iOS Simulator" and "Android Emulator".
However, the state works fine when I switch to class component.

Here is a small example to illustrate this problem:

```js
export default function App() {

  const [name, setName] = useState("Mark");

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{ name }</Text>
      <Button title="Change name" onPress={() => setName("Eric")} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

When I click the button I change "Mark" to "Eric". But when I modify the code (lets say, I add a simple `<Text>Hello</Text>` component) and save it I still see the latest value in the state "Eric".

Normally the component is supposed to reload when I make changes to the code and therefore display the initial value "Mark". Am I right? So what's wrong here? Is there any recent changes to "useState" behavior?

By the way, I use the following versions in my projet:

- expo-cli 4.1.6 (Same problem with version 4.0.17 too)
- watchman 4.9.0
- node 14.15.4 LTS

Dependencies:

- expo: ~40.0.0
- react: 16.13.1
- react-dom: 16.13.1
- react-native:
  "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz"

Dev Dependencies:

- @babel/core: ~7.9.0

Comment: The problem is due to `fast-refresh`. Open your developer menu and disable `fast-refresh`. You could view this link of what it does -> https://reactnative.dev/docs/fast-refresh

Comment: This should help you :- https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging

Comment: No. it's not caused by fast-refresh. I desabled it and it doesn't solve the problem at all..

Comment: In your simulator, press `Command + d` and choose `reload` option.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I am not supposed to reload manually my app. As soon as I save changes in my VSCode, the app should refresh automatically. This is the normal behaviour and its also the easiest way.